# Check if a list contain element of a csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a csv file with items like these:  some,foo,bar and i have a different list in python with different item like att1,some,bar,try,other . Is possible for every list, create a row in the same csv file and set 1 in correspondence of the 'key' is present and 0 otherwise? So in this case the csv file result would be:

```
some,foo,bar
1,0,1
```

Comment: yes, it's possible. Most things are. Do you have any code you have written to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't any idea @PaulCollingwood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a dictionary with the keys as the column names.

```
csv = {
  "some" : [],
  "foo" : [],
  "bar" : []
}
```

Now, for each list check if the values are in the dict's keys, and append as necessary.

```
for list in lists:
  for key in csv.keys():
    if key in list:
       csv[key].append(1)
    else:
       csv[key].append(0)
```

Comment: With this code, the order of the element is guaranteed? 
Will the 1 and 0 be in the same key column?

Comment: Yes, all the values in one row will be at the same index in all three lists, as we are inserting into all three lists for every key.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, using Pandas.
Let's say the contexts of `example.csv` are:

```
some,foo,bar
```

Then we can represent sample data with:

```
import pandas as pd

keys = ["att1","some","bar","try","other"]
data = pd.read_csv('~/Desktop/example.csv', header=None)

print(data)
      0    1    2
0  some  foo  bar

matches = data.apply(lambda x: x.isin(keys).astype(int))

print(matches)
   0  1  2
0  1  0  1

newdata = pd.concat([data, matches])

print(newdata)
      0    1    2
0  some  foo  bar
0     1    0    1
```

Now write back to CSV:

```
newdata.to_csv('example.csv', index=False, header=False)

# example.csv contents
some,foo,bar
1,0,1
```

Given `data` and `keys`, we can condense it all into one chained command:

```
(pd.concat([data, 
            data.apply(lambda x: x.isin(keys).astype(int))
           ])
   .to_csv('example1.csv', index=False, header=False))
```